# Is it a common practice to exit kill/2 a process?

Tags: erlang

In my app, I plan to have many worker processes, that can potentially spend hours doing their work.

I want the user to be able to *stop* and *delete* the workers.

Is it acceptable to `kill/2, exit` the process?
Will it terminate the process even if it's in the middle of doing some work (i.e. downloading a file)?

Do supervisors offer a similar mechanism for stopping and removing children that are in the middle of doing some work?

Comment: Did you check the [supervisor documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html)?

Comment: @SteveVinoski Yes, my main concern was with unconditional termination. It seems this is so, as I found out below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it acceptable to kill, `exit/2` the process? Will it terminate the
>   process even if it's in the middle of doing some work (i.e.
>   downloading a file)?

Yes. In order to terminate a process you may use `exit/2` as you said. The termination procedure will be different if you set the `Reason` argument to be: `noraml`, `OtherReason` or `kill`.
It is explained very well in the [Error Handling](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#errors) documentation, and also for more detailed explenation see [this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-processes).
So you may choose whatever fits your application.

> Do supervisors offer a similar mechanism for stopping and removing
>   children that are in the middle of doing some work?

Yes. As mentioned in the comment, there is a very good detailed documentation for it in [Erlang's Supervisor](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html) documentation. I suggest you to carefully read all of it, but the main parts you're looking for are:

1. Defining the `child_spec()` when starting a child (mainly the `shutdown` and `restart` option).
2. [`terminate_child/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#terminate_child-2) for the actual termination of a child.
3. [`delete_child/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#delete_child-2) for deleting a child after calling `terminate_child/2`.

You can read more about it [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors#supervisor-concepts).

Comment: Thanks, this part is exactly what I was looking for: "The default behaviour when a process receives an exit signal with an exit reason other than normal, is to terminate... When a process is trapping exits, it does not terminate when an exit signal is received. Instead, the signal is transformed into a message {'EXIT',FromPid,Reason}, which is put into the mailbox of the process, just like a regular message."